TabbedPage / ScrollView issue - sometimes can't scroll
UPDATE: This is a bug within TabbedPage, and a fix is here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/26217/files That is obviously going to take a while before it gets released - is there any way I can easily implement a fix in the mean time?
I have an issue with ScrollView - I believe it's only an issue when the ContentPage is hosted within a TabbedPage (when building for Windows)
Sometimes the page will scroll as expected, and sometimes it won't (resizing the main app causes it to recalculate the ScrollView's status, randomly sometimes incorrectly).
To reproduce, create a page to display in the tabbed page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPageScrollViewIssue.MyChildPage"
             Title="MyChildPage">
    <ScrollView>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Label 1" />
            <Label Text="Label 2" />
            <Label Text="Label 3" />
            <Label Text="Label 4" />
            <Label Text="Label 5" />
            <Label Text="Label 6" />
            <Label Text="Label 7" />
            <Label Text="Label 8" />
            <Label Text="Label 9" />
            <Label Text="Label 10" />
            <Label Text="Label 11" />
            <Label Text="Label 12" />
            <Label Text="Label 13" />
            <Label Text="Label 14" />
            <Label Text="Label 15" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

Then create a TabbedPage:
public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        Children.Add(new MyChildPage());

    }
}

Set your MainPage to be a new instance of MyTabbedPage.

Reduce the height of the app so only Labels 1 to 10 are visible.
When I try to scroll, I can only scroll down to Label 11! Slowly
Change the width of the main window by clicking the right hand edge of the app window - you will see the vertical
scrollbar change size! Sometimes it's too big to see the bottom of
it, in which case you can't scroll to the bottom, but sometimes you
CAN see a gap at the bottom, in which case you can scroll !
The page
is now correctly scrollable down to the last label, Label 15!

This is how it should look: (and correctly allows scrolling)

But by changing the width, it can end up like this, and doesn't allow scrolling to the bottom:

I have logged this on GitHub, others have been able to reproduce the issue. But this is a big issue for my app that I am converting from Xamarin Forms. I can't go live with this random behaviour, so if anyone has any suggestions for getting around the issue, I would be very grateful!
The issue is logged here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/26103
UPDATE:
This is a bug within TabbedPage, and a fix is here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/26217/files
That is obviously going to take a while before it gets released - is there any way I can easily implement a fix in the mean time?

ScrollView HeightRequest 500 and roll.

Oh my! That makes things even worse, in that the child page ends up rendering over the top of the TabbedPage!

But you can now scroll all at least. (I would put a Grid as outmost element, and inside the 500 height scrollview.)

I must be missing something, but a top level Grid, with the ScrollView inside it, then the StackLayout, doesn't appear to scroll at all! (and still renders over the TabbedPage parent)

Sparky, I gave you example, and small explanation what is happening. Read it. Try it. Experiment a bit, if it is not clear. If you still have questions about it, I will answer them.

Can you tell me the platform you are using? Also, you mentioned changing the width and height, is this a dynamic process, please give  me more detailed code .

Hi @liyu - thanks for asking for more detail. I'm using Windows, and I get inconsistent results by dragging the edge of the app window to change the width. By changing the width, it appears to randomly pick one of two heights for the ScrollView - one is correct and one is wrong.

"is there any way I can easily implement a fix in the mean time" -- build your own MAUI assemblies with the updated code. MAUI isn't an opaque system that you need to wait on MS to fix, it's fully open source and can be built by anyone. And when the fix is officially released, you can revert back to the nuget version.

@Blindy Thanks for the suggestion :-) Yep I could do that but I was hoping for an easier fix, such as some code to use in a custom renderer or is there some way to in effect override that private method in TabbedPage which is causing the problem ( OnNavigationViewSizeChanged) - I know it's a long shot but ya never know...

Lets modify your code with some numbers:
<Grid>
    <ScrollView HeightRequest="200" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Label 1" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 2" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 3" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 4" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 5" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 6" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 7" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 8" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 9" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 10" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 11" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 12" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 13" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 14" HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Label Text="Label 15" HeightRequest="50"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>

With this modification, you will see 4 labels in the scroll. And you will be able to scroll to the bottom.
The height of the scroll view is fixed. It will remain 200, no matter how many times you resize the page. If the page height is smaller, say 100, then you still can scroll, but you will not see the bottom half of the scroll view. So once you scroll to label 15, you will actually see label 13.
(The bottom of the Scroll View is under the page bottom)
This is what you are observing. You resize the page, you assume that the scroll view (the content, or say "child") is resizing with it. But you cant be any further away from the truth...
Recalculations of sizes/position is in order. And MAUI is just terrible at it. So either play with fixed ("magic") numbers, or attempt to do the resizing alone.

Alas going through and adding height requests to all my controls isn't really a viable option. This is quite a serious bug, it just randomly seems to recalculate correctly sometimes, and other times not. I'm pulling my hair out....

@Sparky I did not tell you to go and add height request to all your controls. Maybe I wasn't clear, but the size of the child element is what you have to control. Try to do it, and if you have specific problem, I will try to help you solve it.

Sorry, I'm not fully understanding, I'm grateful for your help but the penny is not dropping! Is my example not specific enough?

@Sparky You are describing behavior. You consider this behavior "serious bug". (It is neither serious, nor a bug). I explained to you what actually is happening, and what courses of action you can take. When you start taking those actions, if you encounter a problem, I will try to assist.
